# MySQL Joining three tables

Tags: php, mysql

I am doing a query with three tables, the problem was one table has many occurrences of id of another.

sample data:

```
users: id

answers: 
id:1
user_answer :1
id:1
user_answer :2
id:1
user_answer :3

Questions: 
id:1
answers :answer description
id:2
answers :answer description
id:3
answers :answer description
```

How can I get all user information and all answer and its description, I used GROUP by user.id but it only returns only one answer.

I want to return something like this list all of users answer:

```
Name         Q1          Q2    
USERNAME    ans1,ans2    ans1,ans2             comma separated description of answer here
```

[alt text http://christianruado.comuf.com/images/schema.png](http://christianruado.comuf.com/images/schema.png)

Comment: Could you provide some more detailed database schema including relations?

Comment: I updated my post to upload the schema, does it makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

You'd need to use a pivot table

```
SELECT users.id, users.name, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(q1.answer SEPARATOR ', ') AS `Q1`, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(q2.answer SEPARATOR ', ') AS `Q2`, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(q3.answer SEPARATOR ', ') AS `Q3`
FROM `users` AS users,
    LEFT JOIN `answers` AS a1 ON a1.id = users.id
    LEFT JOIN `questions` AS q1 ON q2.id = a1.user_answer
    LEFT JOIN `answers` AS a2 ON a2.id = users.id
    LEFT JOIN `questions` AS q2 ON q2.id = a2.user_answer
    LEFT JOIN `answers` AS a3 ON a3.id = users.id
    LEFT JOIN `questions` AS q3 ON q3.id = a3.user_answer
WHERE q1.question_id = 1
    AND q2.question_id = 2
    AND q3.question_id = 3
GROUP BY users.id
```

That's my best guess at what you want to do from the schema you provided (I doubt it's complete, which is why I guessed at the question_id part.  I used LEFT JOIN so that if the user doesn't have an answer for that question, it won't hurt anything.  Also, GROUP_CONCAT will automatically combine the field if multiple answers exist.  So if there are 2 rows from Q1 for that particular user, it'll combine the two into "ans1, ans2"...

Comment: GROUP_CONCAT, nice - I didn't know about that function.